# Messy output in zsh working in emacs M-x shell

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, zsh

I have changed my shell to oh-my-zsh, which is working great in iTerm.

However when I open up my Emacs, M-x shell, I see it also changes to zsh, but the output from executing commands is messy:

```
➜  Public  ls
ls


Drop Box    Dropbox-Public  tars
%                                                                                                  


➜  Public  ls
ls


Drop Box    Dropbox-Public  tars
%                                                                                                  


➜  Public
```

Too many empty lines! I have to change it back to bash using:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")
```

However I want to use zsh, since it has great plugins. For example, I can see which branch I am working on currently directly in the command line using the git plugin.

Is there anyone familiar with zsh and emacs who can help me fix this?

Comment: emacs `M-x shell` is a dumb terminal, you're not going to have much luck using advanced zsh features in it =/... And just for the record, you can show git branch it bash as well (I think there's a question here on SU about it).

Answer (score 2):

My zsh look messy as well with the `shell` command. `ansi-term` works better.

If you use the shell from within emacs a lot you could try [MultiTerm](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm).

I have used it for a while, but went back to a terminal shell.